# RxJS switchMap and passing response to another operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, switchmap

Let say I have code like that:

```
            this.apiService.getUrlForPhoto('photo1')
            .switchMap((url) => {
                return this.apiService.uploadPhotoToProvidedUrl(url);
            })
            .switchMap((response) => {
                return this.apiService.confirmPhotoUpload(confirmationToken);
            })
            .subscribe((response) => {
                if (response.confirmed) {
                    console.log('Success');
                }
            });
```

First is http get which returns url where I can post new photo,
Second is http put where I have to upload photo, 
Third is http post where I have to confirm that photo was uploaded to that url.

My question is it is possible to pass url to second switchMap? At second switchMap I have response from uploadPhotoToProviderdUrl method but how can I get  response from previous method?

Comment: what about using a varible? isn't that possible?

Comment: Yes, I did it that way, but I wonder is it any better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your API calls are Observables:

```
this.apiService.getUrlForPhoto('photo1')
    .switchMap((url) => {
        return this.apiService.uploadPhotoToProvidedUrl(url)
            .switchMap((response) => {
                // Here you can use 'url'
                return this.apiService.confirmPhotoUpload(confirmationToken);
            })  
    })
    .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.confirmed) {
            console.log('Success');
        }
    });
```